# Safari 4.0.5 will not play any HTML5 (H.264) video

Tags: windows-7, video, safari, h.264, html5

The [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/) tells me that my browser does not support the <video> element, and when I try example page, I get the fallback message, usually "Your browser does not support HTML5 video."

I know this should work in Safari.  I am on Windows 7, 64-bit (running 32-bit Safari).

Video works in Safari for everyone else in the office.  (Windows 7 setup exactly like mine, Vista, OSX.)

I have tries uninstalling, deleting all user preferences, and reinstalling.  Anything else I should try?

Comment: Found the answer back on stack, Safari uses quicktime to play html5 video, there is no support baked into the browser like there is in Chrome and Firefox. Installing quicktime fixes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394996/how-to-use-the-video-element-on-safari

Comment: you should post that as an answer, wait a couple of days, then accept your answer.  solving your own problem is encouraged here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that Quicktime is installed as well.